How to test Agile Coretime functionality in Zombienet
I want to test the end-to-end functionality of Coretime in ZombieNet. Can anyone please explain the steps involved in this?
Thanks.

For on-demand, please find instructions here

or better yet in the wiki: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-guides-template-basic

Note that the pallet name will be changed with the upcoming release from onDemandAssignmentProvider to just onDemand, remaining guide should remain accurate.

Thank you, It works!!

But here we need to manually go to relay chain and execute the onDemandAssignmentProvider . How do we do that automatically? let's say at at 5PM daily I need a on-demand coretime so what can be the automatic mechanism in which I can get the one coretime at 5PM daily?

We don't have any automation yet out of the box. For a full solution see this ticket. Magnet seems to have already implemented something similar. For #1487: It is currently not a high priority due to perceived low interest in on-demand for now and also because bulk coretime is getting ridiculously cheap on Kusama right now. If you have a good use case for on-demand not covered by bulk, please let us know here: https://forum.polkadot.network/t/on-demand-around-the-corner-what-do-you-want-need/7382

you can check the smoke test on polkadot-sdk, basically is spawning a relaychain with coretime parachain and another para. Then use a couple of js script to configure the relaychain and set the lease on the coretime chain. Ping me if you have questions.
Thanks!

I have run rococo local, coretime chain and parachain template in ZombieNet. Now I need to know the process how I can start the sale and purchase the core and all. So   I would require the end-2 process of assigning the core to the template parachain.

I found this very helpful:  https://polkadot-public.notion.site/Agile-Coretime-FAQ-c930796e8c884011adb1fa24ef22f77c
this article is for bulk coretime. can you please suggest me what are the things that will change for on-demand coretime?
